# GCP Backend service + GPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm following [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/running-tensorflow-inference-workloads-at-scale-with-tensorrt-5-and-nvidia-t4-gpus) tutorial, and is mentioned that I need to configure backend this way, but... I'm using GPU and I care about GPU utilization, Current config is for [CPU utilization](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/update-backend) does backend-services support GPU utilization?

```
gcloud compute backend-services add-backend ${WEB_BACKED_SERVICE_NAME} \
   --balancing-mode UTILIZATION \
   --max-utilization 0.8 \
   --capacity-scaler 1 \
   --instance-group ${INSTANCE_GROUP_NAME} \
   --instance-group-region ${REGION} \
   --global
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the gcloud command [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/add-backend#--balancing-mode) seems like the balancing mode only is supported based on CPU UTILIZATION